# htmlタグをphpで配列にしたいと考えています。

Tags: php, html, array

```
 $str = 'abcdefg<span style="font-size:20px;">hijklmnop</span>qrs<span style="font-size:18px;color=F00;">tuv</span>wxyz';
```

上記のような文字列をphpを使い以下のようにしたいと考えています。

```
Array([0]=>abcdefg,[1]=><span style="font-size:20px;">hijklmnop</span>,[2]=>qrs,[3]=><span style="font-size:18px;color=F00;">tuv</span>,[4]=>wxyz)
```

どのように解決できますでしょうか。

Answer (score 5):

ネストなど考えない簡易的なものであれば、正規表現を使う方法があります。

```
$str = 'abcdefg<span style="font-size:20px;">hijklmnop</span>qrs<span style="font-size:18px;color=F00;">tuv</span>wxyz';
preg_match_all('/(<[^>]+>[^<]+<\/[^>]+>|[^<]+)/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

正規表現の考え方としてですが、

- <hoge>〜</hoge>の間を取得する
- <までの範囲まで取得する

こうすると下記のような結果が得られます。

```
Array
(
    [0] => abcdefg
    [1] => <span style="font-size:20px;">hijklmnop</span>
    [2] => qrs
    [3] => <span style="font-size:18px;color=F00;">tuv</span>
    [4] => wxyz
)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。求めていた挙動が無事再現できました。

Answer (score 1):

phpでjqueryのようにhtmlを扱うならphpqueryというものがあります。
http://qiita.com/zaburo/items/465ca691aebad2b5691e

Comment: phpqueryは知りませんでした。
貴重な情報をありがとうございます。